# Integral of $\frac{1}{2x}$

Tags: integration, logarithms

The integral of $\frac{1}{2x}$ is $\frac{\ln(x)}{2}$, but can't it also be $\frac{\ln(2x)}{2}$ or $\frac{\ln(3x)}{2}$?

Is there a special reason for $\ln(Ax)$ to have identical derivatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate the following identity $$\ln(Ax)=\ln(A)+\ln(x).$$

Comment: As this hints, an arbitrary antiderivative is $$\ln(x)+C=\ln(x)+\ln(e^C)=\ln(e^Cx),$$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider it a consequence of the chain rule. For nonzero constants $A$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln(Ax)
    &=\frac{1}{Ax}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(Ax)\\
    &=\frac{1}{Ax}A\\
    &=\frac{1}{x}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{dx}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2dx}{2x}$$
put $ 2x=u \implies 2dx=du$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} ln(u)$$

$$= \frac{ln(2x)}{2}$$